# Cannot print out a list of module versioning information required by kernel modules using `modprobe --dump-modversions`

Tags: bash, debian, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I want to print out a list of module versioning information required by `ceph.ko` module, using `modprobe`, following a [tutorial](https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/how-i-hacked-play-with-docker-and-remotely-ran-code-on-the-host) on Linux kernel modules.

I've tried to print out the information for several modules (not just `ceph.ko`), but they all result in the following error:

```
modprobe --dump-modversions ceph.ko
modprobe: FATAL: could not get modversions of ceph.ko: No such file or directory
```

In the tutorial, the following is shown:

```
modprobe --dump-modversions ceph.ko | grep printk
0x27e1a049 printk
```

Why can't I print out the module versioning information using `modprobe`?

Info:

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu-parallels 5.8.0-43-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 03:01:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
VERSION_ID="20.10"
VERSION_CODENAME=groovy
```

Comment: Could you share a link to the tutorial you’re following?

Comment: Sure, it's: https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/how-i-hacked-play-with-docker-and-remotely-ran-code-on-the-host - I've also included it in the original post. Please, don't be offended that it's offensive security. I'm very interested in Cloud technology, and work as an engineer securing container workloads.